How do i mount VHDX drive into WSL so it persist after WSL reboots
How to persistently mount a VHDX file in WSL2?
I want to mount a drive in WSL2 using the following command:
wsl --mount --vhd "E:\CustomDrive2.vhdx" --bare

This allows me to bypass /mnt/e, which is slower.
The problem is that this command is not persistent. After rebooting my PC, the mount is lost. When I try to remount it, I get the following error:
Failed to attach disk '\?\E:\CustomDrive2.vhdx' to WSL2: Access is denied.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/MountVhd/HCS/E_ACCESSDENIED
This makes me think that I can't just automate the command with a .bat file in the startup folder or via Task Scheduler.
Is there a way to make the mount persistent, or a --persistent flag I can use so the drive mounts with WSL2 at startup? If not, what’s the best way to automate this process?

wsl.conf [automount], microsoft docs link.
